# How can I parse nested xml (with the same name of childs) to CSV?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, csv, parsing

I am very new to Python, I searched a lot but I could not find the solution. I want to parse the following xml file to a csv file.

```
<List>
  <item>
     <id>5939c5e20d82880efce93933</id>
     <sensorEvents>
        <sensorEvents>
            <avgSped>48.55647532226298</avgSped>
            <completed>true</completed>
        </sensorEvents>
        <sensorEvents>
            <avgSped>39.53368357145088</avgSped>
            <completed>true</completed>
        </sensorEvents>
        <sensorEvents>
            <avgSped>41.41160105233052</avgSped>
            <completed>true</completed>
        </sensorEvents>
     </sensorEvents>
  </item>

  .
  .
  .
  .

</List>
```

The code that I wrote is this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
tree = ET.parse("my_xml_file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
f = open('my_csv_file.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(f)

head = ['ID','avgSped','completed']
csvwriter.writerow(head)

for Item in root.findall('item'):

    for Sensorevents in Item.findall('sensorEvents'):


        row = []
        id_ = Item.find('id').text
        row.append(id_)

        avgSped_ = Sensorevents.find('sensorEvents').find('avgSped').text
        row.append(avgSped_)

        completed_ = Sensorevents.find('sensorEvents').find('completed').text
        row.append(completed_)

        csvwriter.writerow(row)


f.close()
```

And the result is this:

[image]

There are 3 sensorEvents but my code just captures the first one. How can I modify the code to read all of the sensorEvents? 
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `<sensorEvents>` tag containing 3 `<sensorEvents>`, the first `<sensorEvents>` shadows the children `<sensorEvents>` in `<sensorEvents>`.

This means

```
    for Sensorevents in Item.findall('sensorEvents'):
```

Will loop only once per

```
<sensorEvents>
    <sensorEvents>
        <avgSped>48.55647532226298</avgSped>
        <completed>true</completed>
    </sensorEvents>
    <sensorEvents>
        <avgSped>39.53368357145088</avgSped>
        <completed>true</completed>
    </sensorEvents>
    <sensorEvents>
        <avgSped>41.41160105233052</avgSped>
        <completed>true</completed>
    </sensorEvents>
</sensorEvents>
```

Then

```
    avgSped_ = Sensorevents.find('sensorEvents').find('avgSped').text
    row.append(avgSped_)

    completed_ = Sensorevents.find('sensorEvents').find('completed').text
```

Gets the data for **the first tag only**.

You should try

```
for Item in root.findall('item'):
    for root_Sensorevents in Item.findall('sensorEvents'):
        for Sensorevents in root_Sensorevents.findall('sensorEvents'):
...
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using the lxml library because with it you can search by xpath expressions which often make for simpler code.

Here, the xpath expression `.//sensorEvents/sensorEvents` says look for `sensorEvents` elements anywhere in the document and then look for the `sensorEvents` elements *immediately under* these.

Once you have these it's often a simple matter to write expressions for attributes of the elements, as shown.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('temp2.xml')
>>> inner_sensorEvents = tree.xpath('.//sensorEvents/sensorEvents')
>>> for inner_sensorEvent in inner_sensorEvents:
...     inner_sensorEvent.find('avgSped').text, inner_sensorEvent.find('completed').text
... 
('48.55647532226298', 'true')
('39.53368357145088', 'true')
('41.41160105233052', 'true')
```